# TextBox - binding property doesn't refresh itself

Tags: wpf, textbox, refresh, data-binding

I have a textbox which Text property is bound like that

```
   <TextBox Name="txtBox">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Data">

            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

The filed Data can be changed in various places in my program. However if I change filed Data in ahother control, the t txtBox Text property does't refresh itself. I still can see the old value(despite the fact that Data filed has been changed).
Is there any way to force textbox to refresh itselft or sth?

Answer (score 5):

In order for your textbox to know when the data it's bound to changes, the class that it is bound to must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Below is an example in C#.  If you bind a textbox to the property Data, the textbox should update when the Data property's setter is executed.  Note that INotifyPropertyChanged will require a reference to the System.ComponentModel namespace (a Using in C# or Imports in VB).

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _data;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }

        set
        {
            _data = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll give it a chance :) However I would like to know if  there is any way to refresh textbox.text properryy manually.
Sth like textbox.refresh() ??

Comment: One more question. Is there any way to implement this interface and use autoproperty ??
Basicly all properties in my class are implemented this way

public DateTime Date { get; set; }

Comment: Regarding manual refreshing, it depends on whether you want to do it by accessing the control directly from the view or indirectly from the viewmodel.  The example I provided indirectly causes the binding to update from the viewmodel.  So it comes down to whenever you raise the OnPropertyChanged event.  You can raise the event any time you want - it doesn't necessarily have to be in the setter.

Comment: Regarding automatic properties, the compiler creates a private backer and implements the getter and setter for you. I don't know of any other way to raise the OnPropertyChanged when the setter is called without implementing the setter yourself.

Comment: Once again thanks for answers :) I used INotifyPropertyChange, this is great :)

Answer (score 0):

does your Data property owner object implement INotifyPropertyChanged?
if no than implemet it and fire PropertyChanged When your set property is called